# How to use zlib in kernel extension projects for mac os x?

Tags: c, macos, zlib, inflate, kernel-extension

I want to develop a network kernel extension on mac os. I got some data with gzip format in function sf_data_in(). I included the header file named `<libkern/zlib.h>`, and my mac crashed when it was running the code below after I loading the kext with "kextload".

```
z_stream strm;
bzero(&strm, sizeof(z_stream));

if (Z_OK != inflateInit2(&strm))
{
    printf("inflateInit error.\n");

    inflateEnd(&strm);

    return 0;
}
```

who can tell me how to use it in kernel programming. it's much better to give some samples. 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong number of parameters to `inflateInit2()`, it requires both a pointer  to a stream and the window size in bits. if you do not wish to set the latter, use `inflateInit()` instead.

You may also want to look at some of the kernel code using zlib, [ppp_deflate.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.22.73/bsd/net/ppp_deflate.c), [ipcomp_core.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.22.73/bsd/netinet6/ipcomp_core.c)

Answer (score 0):

I found some use of the zlib kernel library in the [arch/powerpc/boot/gunzip_util.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=arch/powerpc/boot/gunzip_util.c;h=ef2aed0f63ca8c6eb9523495513b0fc008fa96fa;hb=HEAD) file, maybe it will be a good starting point for your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But gunzip is for Linux,  can you please tell me how to use zlib as kernel extension in Mac OS X or some other solutions.  Thanks again!

Comment: @kyle : oh, I didn't notice that was in OSX kernel, I just notice the kernel word... :(